# How to perform a cascading deleting in MongoDB or Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working on an e-commerce project in Express and MongoDB. I'm confused with architecture on how to make relationship between two models such that if I delete one element from a table, all of it's associations should be deleted. CASCADE delete, if I'm using the correct term.

I'm not a database designer, just learning Express and MongoDB. So apologies if my schema is not that good.

I have two tables (or documents in MongoDB). One is Order with schema below:

```
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
shippingInfo : {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Address'
},
user : {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
},
orderItems: [
    {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'OrderItem'
    }
],
totalPrice: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    default: 0.0
},
status: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['processing', 'shipped', 'delivered','cancelled'],
    default: 'processing'
},
 deliveredAt: {
    type: Date,
}

})
```

and OrderItems

```
const orderItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
product: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Product'
},
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
quantity: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
},
price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
},
image: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},

})
```

I want if I delete an Order, all of its OrderItems should be deleted right away (using remove middleware in Order).
I know that Django has something called `on_delete=model.CASCADE` when we create relationships, but I'm unaware of such thing in Mongoose.

I don't want to explicitly make another API request to search for and delete all OrderItems that are referenced in orderItems array in an Order, once it is deleted. There has to be a better approach for this.

Another post on Stack Overflow suggested that in remove middleware of Order I should do something like

```
OrderItem.find({ order_id: this._id }).remove().exec();
```

That would require me to refer **order_id** in **OrderItem** right?
And this would create circular dependency since OrderItem would require Order to be created first and vice versa.

What should I do here? Should I change the schema for both tables i.e. remove orderItems entry from Order and instead add order_id in OrderItem? Or is there a Mongoose way to overcome this situation?

Comment: There is no cascade delete in MongoDB. This will definitely require either separate method for deleting related documents or a middleware. If needed, I can try to provide such example.

Comment: Yes, That would be helpful. Thank you

Comment: Ok, I’ll try that tomorrow as I’m not on my PC right now

Comment: Sorry, forgot, still relevant?

Comment: @Gytis TG could you provide the example? Using Events in node would be a good approach? Pre and post hooks? or middleware?